# Select Different Column Value for Row with Max Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm hoping for a cleaner way to do something that I know how to do one way. I want to retrieve the UserId for the MAX ID value as well as that MAX ID value. Let's say I have a table with data like this:

```
ID  UserId  Value  
1   10      'Foo'  
2   15      'Blah'  
3   10      'Blech'  
4   20      'Qwerty'
```

I want to retrieve:

```
ID   UserId  
4    20
```

I know I could do this like so:

```
SELECT
 t.ID,
 t.UserID
FROM
(
 SELECT MAX(ID) as [MaxID]
 FROM table
) as m
JOIN table as t ON m.MaxID = t.ID
```

I'm only vaguely familiar with the ROW_NUMBER(), RANK() and other similar methods and I can't help believing that this scenario could benefit from some such method to get rid of joining back to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use `ROW_NUMBER` for something like this:

```
with t1Rank as
(
  select *
    , t1Rank = row_number() over (order by ID desc)
  from t1 
)
select ID, UserID
from t1Rank
where t1Rank = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56f5d/1).

The advantage with this approach is you can bring `Value` (or other fields as required) into the result set, too. Plus you can tweak the ordering/grouping as required.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the quick and succinct response. I really should bone up on ROW_NUMBER.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do it with a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT  ID ,
        UserID
FROM    table
WHERE   ID = ( SELECT   MAX(ID)
               FROM     table
             );
```

Comment: Good point, I've certainly used this sort of query before in the past, but like my original example, it means selecting out of the table twice.

Comment: That's ok, it can actually be quicker (depending on the indexes on the table etc) using a subquery in this way, if you create a table the same as the one you specified in your question and look at the execution plans, you will see the subquery is a lot quicker, especially with more rows due to the costly sort operation.  Adding an index on UserID helps with that, but the subquery can still be quicker.

Comment: In fact, if you look at the plans for the query that I suggested and the one that you originally specified, on my machine the optimiser has actually generated the exact same plan for both.  If you then add an index on UserID so that the sort is already done, the optimiser uses the same plan for your query, my query, and the one from t-clausen.dk, it just becomes a select top from the table as because of the ordered index

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the additional details. Like most every other discussion on SQL queries, there rarely is a definitive best way of doing something. In my original post I mentioned ROW_NUMBER as I was angling to use this question as a learning opportunity and I certainly knew about the sub-query option (although I should have included it in my original post to acknowledge that).

Comment: No worries, I always find it interesting with SQL server to get multiple queries that will return the same result in the same query window, then run them so that you can see their execution plans so you can see which is the fastest and how you can change them or add indexes to make them faster, often you see that no matter what way you do it, the optimiser picks the same (usually best) method anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, UserID FROM <table> ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: Another good solution, and, again, one I've used before. I'm curious about the performance difference between this and ROW_NUMBER()... For my particular needs, I am not concerned with performance but for future reference that would be good to know. A quick google search didn't give me any answers.

Comment: @ledbutter in this situation this is the fastest solution, but if you needed highest ID and the matching userID along with the value. Then you would need row_number() over (partition by value order by id desc) rn....... where rn = 1 --in Ian's answer